# Django Haystack Rebuild Index

Tags: django-haystack, whoosh

I was reading the 'Getting Started' guide of Haystack and tried to implement Whoosh backend for my website with Haystack. I was successful in setting up the whole project and I can also see the search box on my search.html template. I am unable to build the index though.

When I type ./manage.py rebuild_index, I get the error:

**Unknown command: rebuild_index**

I know this is a trivial issue. I am unable to understand how the manage.py file can ever understand commands that were not originally a part of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have `haystack` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

`manage.py` learns new commands by importing the `settings.py` file and loading modules from your `INSTALLED_APPS` variable.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was the problem. I did not have haystack in INSTALLED_APPS. I did not know that manage.py loads modules from installed apps.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess that's how manage.py also loads modules - views, urls, admin, models etc. when we run the development server (./manage.py runserver) for all the usual apps of the website.

Comment: That's how it does it for the real server, too.

Comment: simple solutions to simple problems. +1