# Installing django-haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

Super simple question: I went through the "getting start" doc for haystack (using whoosh; I installed both python-whoosh and haystack using pip (first time using it)), and I simply cannot run python manage.py rebuild_index. I get this error:

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
Unknown command: 'rebuild_index'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage
```

I do have 'haystack' listed in my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525765/django-haystack-rebuild-index) doesn't seem to work for me. I also don't get import errors when I run "import haystack" so it does exist. I tried this on my existing project as well as a brand new object made just for this and I just can't get it to work.

However, when I import haystack after `python manage.py shell` and try `haystack.__version__` I get "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**version**'". I get a similar error if I try `haystack.management`: it has no management attribute.

It must be something super simple I'm missing. Thank you for reading this!

Answer (score 17):

Did you perhaps install the wrong thing? This (embarrassingly) happend to me just today. Make sure you install 'django-haystack' and not just 'haystack' (and you will have to remove 'haystack', since it conflicts with 'django-haystack').

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you have the path to haystack in your Python path? (Either the `PYTHONPATH` shell variable or the `sys.path` Python list.)
2. Did you run `python manage.py syncdb`?
3. Does `python manage.py shell` followed by `import haystack` work?
4. After `import haystack`, what do you get for `haystack.__version__`?
5. In the same shell, type the following. Do you get errors for any of them?

   - `haystack.management.commands`
   - `haystack.management.commands.rebuild_index`
   - `haystack.management.commands.rebuild_index.Command.help`

Comment: Following your edit: it seems the import was misleading! I used to have errors on the import and fixed them. Now this happens:

(1) Yes: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages is in the path, and that's the folder that "haystack" is in. (2) Yes. (3) Yes. (4) I get an error! "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'" (5) Same error: "'module' object has no attribute'management'"

Comment: ... `import haystack` followed by `help(haystack)`? Sorry for the late response, I wasn't notified of your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error that you did, and fixed it by removing the old .egg and installing directly from the latest version. You can use easy_install:

```
easy_install https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/zipball/v1.2.4
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - for whatever reason, the haystack version in pip is quite old and obsolete (v 0.6 as of today). To use django-haystack check out the v1. [source](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/).

It compiles and installs simply with

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm - Like David I had installed 'haystack' not 'django-haystack' grumble.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and hadn't set HAYSTACK_SITECONF in my settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `python manage.py rebuild_index` try using `./manage.py rebuild_index`

Answer (score 0):

just do 
   `pip uninstall haystack` and

```
pip install django-haystack
```